# sqlite update not releasing memory on HTC desire

Tags: android, sqlite

Running my app on an HTC Desire (android version 2.3.3) I noticed memory usage increasing when calling the following function:

```
private static final String TABLE_MODULES = "tbl_module1";
private static final String MOD1_INCLUDE = "mod1_include";

private void setItemInclude (int idx, boolean include)
{
    String incString = "";
    if (include)
        incString = "true";
    else
        incString = "false";

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(MOD1_INCLUDE, incString);
    database.update(TABLE_MODULES,args,"_id="+idx,null);
}
```

where database is of type SQLiteDatabase and was obtained from a call to dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() and where dbHelper is derived from SQLiteOpenHelper and instantiated with the application context.

I get the desired update, but when I check the data usage of my application it appears to increase by about 60KB per call and is not released unless dbHelper.close() is called. Multiple calls to this function result in SQLiteDiskIOException.

I have tried `database.rawQuery()`, which also updates correctly but hangs on to memory similarly.

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_MODULES + " SET MOD1_INCLUDE = " + "'" + incString + "'" + " WHERE _id ='" + idx + "'";

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(updateQuery, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.close();
```

Running the same code on an Asus (android 4.0.3) and an Orange San Francisco (android 2.1.update1) does not have this problem.

`getWritableDatabase` is called from the activity's `onCreate()` and the resulting database is closed in `onDestroy()`. I thought that it was ok to keep the database open for the duration of the activity. Any ideas as to what is the cause?

Comment: Use MAT to determine specifically what is not being released and who hold onto it.

Comment: Thanks. That looks very useful. Downloaded it, dumped the heap, converted the output and opened it in MAT. Working out what it is showing me is going to keep me quiet for a while. Will report back when I know more.

Comment: @ndsmyter - thanks for tidying up my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is causing the problem.

On the HTC, each time `database.update()` is called a temporary file is updated in the application's **databases** directory. This file has the extension **.sqlite-wal**. This file gets bigger (by 60KB) on each call and is only deleted when I close the database.

The ASUS also creates a temporary file but with the extension **.sqlite-journal**. This file is also updated on each `update()` call, but once the transaction completes the file's size reduces to zero. So, no memory problems result.

I am not sure what the difference is between Journal and Wal but believe that they are both to do with rolling back a database after a failed transaction. I have solved the memory problem with the following code, which turns off the journal/wal feature.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.close();
```

Calling this after opening the database appears to prevent these temporary files from being created.

However, I am not confident that this is a good idea. I was surprised not to find others reporting this issue and wonder if leaving the database open ready for multiple transactions is considered bad practice? I am new to SQL and have fairly limited experience with databases.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) is quite clear.

> The WAL journaling mode uses a write-ahead log instead of a rollback
>   journal to implement transactions.

In your case it sounds like [automatic checkpointing](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint) is either not configured or not working. You probably don't want to turn journaling off as it can result in data loss.